# How can Tensors produce Vectors (and higher order Tensors) if they, by definition, produce elements of a Field?

Tags: tensors

I understand that by definition, a Tensor is a map (multilinear) that sends the Cartesian product of an arbitrary number of vectors and covectors to real numbers (I'd like to keep everything here in terms of finite-dimensional, real vector spaces). So how can the result of a tensor (given an arbitrary number of vector and covector inputs) be anything other than a real number (which I'm presumably calling a scalar)?

Clearly it can, because in engineering we always talk about "tensors" acting on "vectors" to produce other "vectors". For instance, the result of the Cauchy stress tensor (a (1,1) tensor??) acting on the normal vector of a plane is a traction vector. Or going even further, the elasticity tensor (a (2,2) tensor?), takes the strain tensor ((1,1)) as input and gives you back the stress tensor (another (1,1) tensor).

Am I missing something very trivial or fundamental about the definition of Tensors that allows for all of these results to be possible? Can anyone give me examples? Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes you can partially contract a tensor, i.e. feed it only one of the several arguments and look at the map produced (as it is, by definition then, a map of one argument less to a field). Maybe an easy example is that of a matrix acting on a vector. Take the identity $I$, and define it to be a bi-linear map $I(v,w) = v^T Iw$ (this is the dot product). This is a tensor, and multiplication $Iw = w$ takes a vector to a vector.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose one has a $(1,1)$ tensor $T$. The initial definition of this is that it is a multilinear map $V^* \times V \to \mathbb{R} $, as you say, i.e. one feeds it a covector $\omega$ and a vector $v$, and it outputs a scalar $T(\omega;v)$.

What happens if we take this map, and feed it just a vector? We get $T(-;v)$, which is a map that takes a covector as an argument and gives a scalar, i.e. $T(-;v): V^* \to \mathbb{R}$. So $T(-;v)$ is actually a linear functional on $V^*$, i.e. an element of $V^{**}$. But of course $V^{**}$ is canonically isomorphic to $V$, and so linear functionals on $V^*$ can be identified unambiguously with vectors. Hence $T(-;v)$ is a vector, $T_v$, say. Unpacking this, the map $v \mapsto T_v$ is therefore a linear map $V \to V$.

Exactly the same idea applies to higher rank tensors, although obviously the permutations possible increase considerably with the rank.